# Create a Taxonomy Archive Block

Tags: views, 6

Hello i was hoping to create a block to attach to the taxonomy/term/* page but i am running into problems with the date arguement working with the term argument. I have just cloned the archive view and disabled the taxonomy view, added the arguments but to no avail.

Has anyone ever achieved this before with D^ and Views 3?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make any sense. You say your problem is "the date argument", but it's unclear what that argument is supposed to be doing. You want to create a block that does what?

Comment: hi Letharion. I was wanting to add a block to each taxonomy term page that lets me browse the term by date (just like the archive block.) Think Archive block but have it working on a term argument and only showing nodes belowing to the term. I dont think it is possible from what i can gather.

Comment: If your trying to expose a date in the url it's can be a tricky problem. If you can elaborate on how exactly with a couple sample urls in your question it would help others answer your question. taxonomy/[term]/[dd]-[mm]-[yyyy]/[nid] for example? Or it something else? Or is it problems with the date argument not being exposed or filtered properly in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views While not taxonomy should work. Change the content type from node to taxonomy and as you create it it will be archived. You may need to ad a date entity to the taxonomy and have rules or trigger put in a creation date since I don't believe they are creation date stamped.

Comment: thanks ransom but ive tried that before and ran into problems due to the term argument being alongside the date argument. ill go give it a go but i dont think its gonna work.

Comment: sorry a typo in the first post. this is for D6. tx

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/date You tried that for handling the dates?

Comment: i will just go and try it all again just now ransom and tell you my problems. i was just finishing something up there. wont be long and thanks for your attention

Comment: mmmm either moving up to Views 3 in the past few weeks or my basic Views knowledge has improved ransom as im half way there now. Ive added a block view to my default taxonomy view with the arguments Arguments
Taxonomy: Term ID
Node: Created year + month
  Style: List

Comment: sorry....and that block displays fine. Ive added the same arguments to my taxonomy/term/* page and it is accepting the arguments just fine too. The only problem i have now is to display all terms if the argument is not used.ie folks arrive in a tag term page and it shows all nodes in that term before they click the archive block. The problem seems to be what to do with the Created year and month when there is no argument. Currently i get a blank page as you can see here http://onlinebanter.com/forum/video-games

Comment: As a work around, and possibly better for me, is to create a new View and just show the block in the term page as i was wanting to use a differant style for that view anyhow. I will go and play about with it and anything you can offer to the original problem would be helpfull to me. I will mark this as fixed in a bit i feel.

Comment: That's grate I hope that link helped get you going in the right direction.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers